# Connection error postgresql using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, cs50

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:114920@localhost/Databases")
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():
    Railway = db.execute("SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM Railway").fetchall()
    for railway in Railway:
        print(f"{railway.origin} to {railway.destination}, {railway.duration} minutes")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and got this error
(if possible pls share code I'm stuck at this foe a long time)

> C:\Web Development\Lecture02>python hoja1.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Web Development\Lecture02\hoja1.py", line 6, in 
> engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:114920@localhost/Databases")
> File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine_*init*_.py", line 500, in create_engine
> return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 87, in create
> dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
> File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\psycopg2.py", line 778, in dbapi
> import psycopg2
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

Comment: Hi, you are missing psycopg2 module which is sqlalchemy using for interacting with postgresql. Do you have it installed? `pip install psycopg2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you dont have psycopg2 module
try pip installing psycopg2
run this command in your terminal

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
```

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:114920@localhost:5432/postgres")
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():
Railway = db.execute("SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM Railway").fetchall()
for railway in Railway:
print(f"{railway.origin} to {railway.destination}, {railway.duration} minutes")

if **name** == "**main**":
main()